# Using Interface builder and XIB, UIlabel with text in different colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, xib

- I need to create a LaunchScreen.xib (using Interface builder)
- I want to have a label with text in different color and font size.

Is it possible to have UIlabel with text in different colors using IB? If so, how?

I have accomplished the same programmatically elsewhere in my application. However, I dont know how to do it using IB.

Please provide pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it but it's not easy, and it might not work as well as you'd like. Still, if you look very very carefully, you'll see that the nib editor (Interface Builder) does include, at the top of the Attributes inspector of a UILabel, a Text pop-up that you can change from Plain to Attributed — and then you get a whole different interface, rather ingenious and elaborate, for setting the attributes of different (selected) parts of the text.

This screen shot, for example, is *one* UILabel, with the first word one color and the second word a different color. This was set up entirely in Interface Builder - no code involved:

[image]

Here is the interface you are looking for to set that sort of thing up:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot....why did you mention "it might not work as well as you'd like".......if you could please elaborate......I will accept the answer anyways....at least in Simulator it does what I expect

Comment: Im kind of confused as to how this was hard to do. It was very easy and worked perfectly for me. Just highlighted the text i wanted colored, and colored it.

Comment: @Ryan Sure, if your needs are simple, it's adequate.